# NetworkManager needs frequent restarts, never able to get past: 'getting IP configuration'

Tags: linux, networking, networkmanager

On Fedora-38, the route table (ip r) is constantly turning empty. I can fix it for a few minutes by restarting the NetworkManager (systemctl restart NetworkManager).  Need to fix that permanently.  Suggestions?

Other observed weirdness...
Sometimes, I can find (nmcli dev wifi) two BSSIDs for the same 2.4GHz WiFi network.  What could cause that?

```
$ nmcli con show

NAME       UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE

3c58ac2.4  e45b3590-2220-4dbd-8d0e-1ee7b0fdfd30  wifi      wlp5s0

enp9s0     db7b61ca-c55d-39a0-bd3d-1b6bb4d3319e  ethernet  enp9s0

enp8s0     44801890-09c3-31eb-a8aa-9f21d0b17aa9  ethernet  enp8s0

lo         066efe99-1082-4b10-b7f7-8edb641530dd  loopback  lo    

3c58ac5    50615f69-30fd-411a-b3bd-39e0858e30a6  wifi      --
```

```
$ nmcli dev status

DEVICE          TYPE      STATE                                  CONNECTION

lo              loopback  connected (externally)                 lo        

wlp5s0          wifi      connecting (getting IP configuration)  3c58ac2.4  

enp8s0          ethernet  connecting (getting IP configuration)  enp9s0    

enp9s0          ethernet  connecting (getting IP configuration)  enp8s0    

p2p-dev-wlp5s0  wifi-p2p  disconnected
```

What you can't see is all three interfaces (wlp5s0, enp8s0, enp9s0) shown in brown (presumably because they're all 'getting IP configuation'.  Sometimes Internet access is available when they're all brown, the decider seems to be the kernel having a non-empty route table (ip r).

The NetworkManager is constantly sending notifications that an interface has been deactivated because the IP configuration was unavailable.

The network interfaces have been (fully?) configured in System Settings Connections with the router and a pair of google DNS servers specified for each interface.

UPDATE: 1) The LAN interfaces do get to green state now (and stop showing 'getting IP configuration', but the WiFi interface doesn't go along. 2) The route table still gets reset all by itself (for reasons unknown).  Sometimes restarting the NetworkManager isn't enough to bring the route table back, and I have to restart the interfaces (which I do before resetting the NetworkManager).

What am I missing?

---

Here's some log file excerpts...

```
$ systemctl status NetworkManager
Jul 15 23:30:28 Level10 NetworkManager[1854614]: <info>  [1689489028.6690] device (wlp5s0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> scanning
Jul 15 23:30:28 Level10 NetworkManager[1854614]: <info>  [1689489028.6690] device (p2p-dev-wlp5s0): supplicant management interface state: inactive -> scanning
Jul 15 23:30:53 Level10 NetworkManager[1854614]: <warn>  [1689489053.9743] device (wlp5s0): Activation: (wifi) association took too long, failing activation
Jul 15 23:30:53 Level10 NetworkManager[1854614]: <info>  [1689489053.9744] device (wlp5s0): state change: config -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 15 23:30:53 Level10 NetworkManager[1854614]: <info>  [1689489053.9748] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Jul 15 23:30:53 Level10 NetworkManager[1854614]: <info>  [1689489053.9927] device (wlp5s0): set-hw-addr: set MAC address to 46:C8:DC:B1:46:65 (scanning)
Jul 15 23:30:53 Level10 NetworkManager[1854614]: <warn>  [1689489053.9969] device (wlp5s0): Activation: failed for connection '3c58ac5'
Jul 15 23:30:53 Level10 NetworkManager[1854614]: <info>  [1689489053.9970] device (wlp5s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
Jul 15 23:30:53 Level10 NetworkManager[1854614]: <info>  [1689489053.9970] device (p2p-dev-wlp5s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> disconnected
Jul 15 23:30:53 Level10 NetworkManager[1854614]: <info>  [1689489053.9973] device (wlp5s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
```

---

```
$ journalctl -b -u NetworkManager -n 40
Jul 15 23:35:31 Level10 NetworkManager[1854614]: <warn>  [1689489331.3181] device (wlp5s0): Activation: failed for connection '3c58ac2.4'
Jul 15 23:35:31 Level10 NetworkManager[1854614]: <info>  [1689489331.3188] device (wlp5s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 15 23:35:31 Level10 NetworkManager[1854614]: <info>  [1689489331.3358] dhcp4 (wlp5s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Jul 15 23:35:31 Level10 NetworkManager[1854614]: <info>  [1689489331.3359] dhcp4 (wlp5s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Jul 15 23:35:31 Level10 NetworkManager[1854614]: <info>  [1689489331.3359] dhcp4 (wlp5s0): state changed no lease
Jul 15 23:35:31 Level10 NetworkManager[1854614]: <info>  [1689489331.3739] device (wlp5s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Jul 15 23:35:31 Level10 NetworkManager[1854614]: <info>  [1689489331.3739] device (p2p-dev-wlp5s0): supplicant management interface state: completed -> disconnected****
```

Comment: `What am I missing?` configuration files. How can we see what you've done wrong if we can't see what you've done

Comment: Which config files interest you?

Comment: Have you checked the log files for any indication of what's happening?

Comment: I'm not sure how (possibly adding the router IP before the pair of google DNS), but I managed to get the LAN I/Fs to stay connected for hours at a time (with no use), but send a single email, and the route table will reset.  Naturally, I did the same for the 2.4 & 5GHz WiFis, but neither of them can connect (yes, they have strong signal). I'll add some journal entries to the main post.

Comment: What do your `wpa_supplicant` logs say about this? (`busctl set-property fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1 /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1 fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1 DebugLevel s debug` if you want more detail.)